# Failed to install pyglet with python3

Tags: windows-7, python

I am using Windows 7 and I have installed Python 3.3. I've downloaded pyglet-1.1.4.msi from [www.pyglet.org](http://www.pyglet.org), but when installing it, it tells me that:

> pyglet requires Python 2.4 or later. The installation will be aborted.

Is there any solution to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

According to Pyglet website, "pyglet 1.2 alpha released. The major 1.2alpha1 release brings pyglet to Python 3". That means pyplet before version 1.2 may not support Python3. You should download pyglet 1.2 and after instead.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't see these words when I check the website. It was my fault.

Comment: @Inzaghi if possible, can you mark the question as answered/solved, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported at version 1.1, if you are going to learn pyglet, use python2 for now.

See http://groups.google.com/group/pyglet-users?hl=en, there are posts about this.

Comment: Missleading information, it is supported. Just not by the major versions but they do give the option for both source and binary package for the version of Pyglet that supports it.

Comment: I did not want to mislead, I was talking about the version 1.1, and if he has not used Pyglet, my advice is that today it is easier to try with python2.

Comment: Bottom line: If you're new, start with Python3 (it will become a standard soon), if you want to use Pyglet, download the latest version that supporst the base platform (pyglet1.2-alpha in this case). Don't start going backwards in tech, it's not a good behavior!